# "total += i;" does not work for some reason

Tags: c++, for-loop

For some reason the "total += i;" wont work and when i go to return "total" it returns as 0.

```
long int sumOfGroup(int k) {
    long int special = (k * k) + (k - 1);
    long int limit =  special - ((k-1) * 2);
    cout << special << " " << limit << endl;
    long int total = 0;
    for(int i = special; i <= limit; i - 2){
        total += i;
    }
    return  total;
}


int main() {
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    long answer = sumOfGroup(k);
    cout << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if you ran this no matter the input the answer is 0. all my other numbers are correct and I am quite sure it has something to do with the for loop.

Comment: `for(int i = special; i <= limit; i - 2)` should be `for(int i = special; i <= limit;i= i - 2)`?

Comment: @BillF still gives 0 as output

Comment: `limit` is less than `special`, surely it's meant to be `for(int i = special; i >= limit; i -= 2)`. That or should `limit` be `special + ((k-1) * 2)` and increasing `i` instead? Or are `special` and `limit` the wrong way round? It's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Isn't `special` always larger than `limit`?

Comment: @NickA either way increasing or decreasing won't work

Comment: @undertaker did you make sure to note the difference between your `<=` in the loop and my `>=`? (as well as the `i -= 2`)

Comment: It's time to learn how to debug simple programs...

Answer (score 0):

Your `total += i` doesn't make any effect because it is never executed!

What are the values of `special` and `limit` printed before you try to enter the loop?

Comment: The fact that it doesn't run doesn't really answer the question ;p, it's clear (I think even to OP that it doesn't run), the question is more why doesn't it

Comment: what do you mean it is no executed? In the code it shows that i print both the values of special and limit. If you k = 3 the special should be equal to 11 and the limit to 7. The total should equal 27. But it doesn't

Comment: @undertaker - The condition in the middle of the `for` is a while-condition, not an until-condition. If `i` is larger that `limit`, the loop will never execute.

Comment: @undertaker If `special` is 11, then the loop starts with assigning 11 to the loop's `i` variable. Then the value of `i` is compared to `limit` to decide whether the loop body shall be executed. Alas, you say `limit` is 7, so the `i<=limit` condition is not satisfied (because '`11<=7`' is not true) and the whole loop is skipped. Why don't you use a debugger (or just print a single star to the output inside the loop) to test if the loop actually executes or not...?

Answer (score 0):

try this for your loop:

```
for(int i = special; i >= limit; i -= 2){
    total += i;
}
```